# Facebook messenger chat bot

Tags: watson-conversation, facebook-messenger-bot

For this I tried two ways.

1.Using stamplay I integrated everything with stamplay (messenger & watson conversation) while deploying in npm (cli)-"***stamplay init***".
It is throwing an error --ssl certificate chain error.

2.Using ngrok I try to run the ***ngrok http 3000***. It is throwing reconnecting && reconnecting

Can any one help me to reslove.

Answer (score 1):

This middleware plugin allows developers to easily integrate a Watson Conversation workspace with multiple social channels like Slack, Facebook, and Twilio. https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware

Comment: can you provide me any sample on facebook messenger with ibm watson conversation.

Answer (score 1):

@RiyaMRoy allows to you one solution.

But you can do this with 2 more options too:

- Use [Node-red](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/how-to-create-a-watson-chatbot-on-nodered/) to Integrate Watson Conversation with facebook easily.
- Use NGROK, Tanmay Bakshi teaches how to do that. Check this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z58O5xU57WA).

I'm currently using node-red and works perfectly. You can create functions inside Node-red, and have a lot options for Business rules.

Comment: I added ngrok i'm getting the get request message in my console ,But it is coming the post requests,Help me to resolve this